# how to submit data in django's database

Tags: django

I have a question about how to enter data in django's database. I have the following Template, in which ' E ' is a variable that get the string:

```
<form action="." method="GET"><input type="text" name="E" style="width: 450px;height: 30px;" /></form>
```

This is my models.py in which I have a class named 'Company' and I want this variable 'E' be saved in 'Subject' :

```
class Company(models.Model):
    Subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Subject
```

Then in views.py I wrote something like this to save the variable in Subject field, it's incomplete, and I want you to help me about it :

```
def Text_Box(request):
    T = request.GET.get(E,' ')
    if T:
        # I don't know how to make an object of class 'Company' so then I save ' T ' in Company.Subject
    else:
        return render_to_response("Base.html") # Base.html is my basic template file
```

I would really appreciate if you help me with it.
Thanks in advance.

Sophia

Comment: check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) or simply dirty `Company(Subject=T)`

Comment: Also keep in mind to Use POST for operations that change data or system state. Use GET for queries that don't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

My first piece of advice is to familiarize yourself with PEP 8, found here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

While it may seem natural to capitalize or not capitalize, it has real meaning to a Python programmer.

My second piece of advice is, start with the django tutorial (provided you already know Python) found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

There is also the django book, found here:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/

My third piece of advice, based on the question you are asking, I think you should familiarize yourself with Python in general.

To answer your question specifically, see okm's comment above, but you can instatiate a model by passing the arguments of the model class to it. This instance you would assign to a variable, let's my_variable and then call "save" on it. However, in your case the save will fail because you also need to pass in the start_time and end_time arguments. Which are not optional.

These can be saved to the model after instantiation also, my_variable.start_time = xx/xxx/xx, for example.

Comment: This is some really great constructive advice.